# kswapd0 jumps near 100%, freezes an EC2 t2.micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, performance-monitoring, atop

I have an EC2 t2.micro instance that I use as a test instance for a web app,

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

the CPU consumption of kswapd0 the process jumps near 100% once in a while, causes a freezes of the instance, and it needs to be rebooted.

Note: "/proc/sys/vm/swappiness" is at default value of 60

I have read that kswapd0 is the process that swaps memory from physical to virtual, so in theory, it should only kick in when memory usage is high.

The mystery is that NO process seems to be going on a memory binge, I have logged resource usage with atop, and below are 3 atop snapshots, take 1 minutes appart.

Here is a summary of the snapshots, we see the free mem going low, and cpu usage going high:

##### atop snapshot1:  cpu 5%,  free mem  242.9M

##### atop snapshot2:  cpu 38%,  free mem  242.5M

##### atop snapshot3:  cpu 99%,  free mem  65.4M

Here are the full snapshots, we can see other variables, on snapshot 2,3  the DSK,MEM and CPU lines are in read (color not shown here...)

Also, the process list in the snapshot is sorted by memory usage, I would expect to see a culprit process with high memory usage, but no process is consuming more than 8%.

```
ATOP - ip-172-31-3-66                                                         2022/10/18  00:00:01                                                         -----------------                                                         1d15h10m16s elapsed
PRC | sys    2m27s | user   6m23s |               |              | #proc    148 |              | #trun     12 | #tslpi   138 |               | #tslpu    44 | #zombie    0 |              | clones 92804 |               |              | #exit     13 |
CPU | sys       0% |              | user      5%  | irq       0% |              |              | idle     94% |              |  wait      0% |              | steal     0% | guest     0% |              |               | curf 2.40GHz |              |
CPL | avg1    0.01 |              | avg5    0.10  |              | avg15   0.15 |              |              |              |  csw 12835910 |              | intr 5959928 |              |              |               | numcpu     1 |              |
MEM | tot   966.2M | free  242.9M | cache 302.3M  | dirty   1.4M | buff    9.4M | slab   59.9M | slrec  26.0M |              |               | shmem 138.0M | shrss   0.0M | shswp   0.0M |              |               |              | numnode    1 |
SWP | tot     0.0M |              | free    0.0M  |              | swcac   0.0M |              |              |              |               |              |              |              | vmcom   1.1G |               | vmlim 483.1M |              |
PAG | scan 6306350 | steal 4335e3 |               | stall      0 | compact    0 | numamig    0 |              | migrate 13e5 |               |              |              |              | swin       0 |  swout      0 |              | oomkill    0 |
PSI | cpusome   4% | memsome   0% |               | memfull   0% | iosome    0% |              | iofull    0% | cs     0/1/3 |               | ms     0/0/0 | mf     0/0/0 |              | is     0/0/0 |  if     0/0/0 |              |              |
DSK |         xvda | busy      0% |               | read  219927 | write 497224 | discrd     0 |              | KiB/r     33 |  KiB/w      7 | KiB/d      0 |              | MBr/s    0.1 | MBw/s    0.0 |  avq     1.51 |              | avio 0.57 ms |
DSK |        xvda1 | busy      0% |               | read  219453 | write 497222 | discrd     0 |              | KiB/r     33 |  KiB/w      7 | KiB/d      0 |              | MBr/s    0.1 | MBw/s    0.0 |  avq     1.51 |              | avio 0.57 ms |
DSK |       xvda15 | busy      0% |               | read     222 | write      2 | discrd     0 |              | KiB/r     42 |  KiB/w      0 | KiB/d      0 |              | MBr/s    0.0 | MBw/s    0.0 |  avq     0.68 |              | avio 1.43 ms |
DSK |       xvda14 | busy      0% |               | read      55 | write      0 | discrd     0 |              | KiB/r     46 |  KiB/w      0 | KiB/d      0 |              | MBr/s    0.0 | MBw/s    0.0 |  avq     0.64 |              | avio 4.22 ms |
NET | transport    | tcpi 1240508 |               | tcpo 1316373 | udpi  148741 | udpo  154146 |              | tcpao  18388 |  tcppo  10357 | tcprs   4413 |              | tcpie    294 | tcpor   3684 |  udpnp   5399 |              | udpie      0 |
NET | network      |              | ipi  1400059  | ipo  1361002 |              | ipfrw      0 | deliv 1400e3 |              |               |              |              |              |              |  icmpi   5402 | icmpo     54 |              |
NET | lo      ---- |              | pcki 1152470  | pcko 1152470 |              | sp    0 Mbps | si  158 Kbps | so  158 Kbps |               |              | coll       0 | mlti       0 | erri       0 |  erro       0 | drpi       0 | drpo       0 |
NET | eth0    ---- |              | pcki  291231  | pcko  213817 |              | sp    0 Mbps | si    8 Kbps | so   14 Kbps |               |              | coll       0 | mlti       0 | erri       0 |  erro       0 | drpi       0 | drpo       0 |
                                                                                            *** System and Process Activity since Boot ***     Rawfile view
    PID          TID       MINFLT       MAJFLT       VSTEXT      VSLIBS        VDATA       VSTACK       LOCKSZ       VSIZE        RSIZE        PSIZE        VGROW        RGROW      SWAPSZ       RUID           EUID            MEM      CMD         1/9
  30705            -        29496          291         2.7M       10.2M        90.1M       132.0K         0.0K      241.5M        78.0M        71.4M       241.5M        78.0M          0B       flask          flask            8%      gunicorn
  30704            -        28672          137         2.7M       10.2M        87.9M       132.0K         0.0K      239.3M        75.6M        69.1M       239.3M        75.6M          0B       flask          flask            8%      gunicorn
    170            -        12586       441557        92.0K        8.8M        49.2M       132.0K         0.0K      227.3M        44.1M        34.2M       227.3M        44.1M          0B       root           root             5%      systemd-journa
  30741            -        58604          984         5.8M       16.5M         7.1M       132.0K         0.0K      215.5M        33.5M        14.7M       215.5M        33.5M          0B       postgres       postgres         3%      postgres
  30739            -        49786          259         5.8M       16.5M         7.7M       132.0K         0.0K      216.1M        32.2M        14.1M       216.1M        32.2M          0B       postgres       postgres         3%      postgres
    212            -         5069           13        80.0K        6.2M        18.0M       132.0K       282.5M      282.5M        26.7M        22.7M       282.5M        26.7M          0B       root           root             3%      multipathd
    496            -        13376         1966        18.7M        1.8M       166.2M       132.0K         0.0K      710.3M        22.8M        25.3M       710.3M        22.8M          0B       root           root             2%      snapd
  30699            -        11046           22         2.7M        5.6M        21.0M       132.0K         0.0K       39.1M        22.0M        16.7M        39.1M        22.0M          0B       flask          flask            2%      gunicorn
    658            -       197263         2185         5.8M       16.3M         2.0M       132.0K         0.0K      210.1M        15.6M         4.1M       210.1M        15.6M          0B       postgres       postgres         2%      postgres
  92773            -          430            0        63.6M        3.4M         8.7M       132.0K         0.0K       78.0M        14.5M         9.4M        78.0M        14.5M          0B       flask          flask            2%      node
    720            -          872           52         5.8M       16.3M         2.2M       132.0K         0.0K      210.3M        14.0M         4.0M       210.3M        14.0M          0B       postgres       postgres         1%      postgres
    476            -         3103           56         2.7M        8.4M        10.4M       132.0K         0.0K       32.4M        13.2M         9.6M        32.4M        13.2M          0B       root           root             1%      networkd-dispa
    638            -         2551           27         2.7M       11.0M        17.1M       132.0K         0.0K      107.5M        11.0M         8.2M       107.5M        11.0M          0B       root           root             1%      unattended-upg
      1            -       156940          747       896.0K        8.8M        19.4M
```

```
ATOP - ip-172-31-3-66                                                            2022/10/18  00:00:01                                                            -----------------                                                            1s elapsed
PRC | sys    0.03s | user   0.02s |               |              | #proc    149 |              | #trun     12 | #tslpi   148 |               | #tslpu    44 | #zombie    0 |              | clones    12 |               |              | #exit      0 |
CPU | sys      38% |              | user     62%  | irq       0% |              |              | idle      0% |              |  wait      0% |              | steal     0% | guest     0% |              |               | curf 2.40GHz |              |
CPL | avg1    0.01 |              | avg5    0.10  |              | avg15   0.15 |              |              |              |  csw      297 |              | intr      84 |              |              |               | numcpu     1 |              |
MEM | tot   966.2M | free  242.5M | cache 304.1M  | dirty   1.4M | buff    9.4M | slab   60.0M | slrec  26.1M |              |               | shmem 138.0M | shrss   0.0M | shswp   0.0M |              |               |              | numnode    1 |
SWP | tot     0.0M |              | free    0.0M  |              | swcac   0.0M |              |              |              |               |              |              |              | vmcom   1.1G |               | vmlim 483.1M |              |
PSI | cpusome  11% | memsome   0% |               | memfull   0% | iosome    1% |              | iofull    0% | cs     0/1/3 |               | ms     0/0/0 | mf     0/0/0 |              | is     0/0/0 |  if     0/0/0 |              |              |
DSK |         xvda | busy     31% |               | read      44 | write      3 | discrd     0 |              | KiB/r     41 |  KiB/w     29 | KiB/d      0 |              | MBr/s    1.8 | MBw/s    0.1 |  avq     0.80 |              | avio 0.85 ms |
DSK |        xvda1 | busy     31% |               | read      44 | write      3 | discrd     0 |              | KiB/r     41 |  KiB/w     29 | KiB/d      0 |              | MBr/s    1.8 | MBw/s    0.1 |  avq     0.80 |              | avio 0.85 ms |

    PID          TID       MINFLT       MAJFLT       VSTEXT      VSLIBS        VDATA       VSTACK       LOCKSZ       VSIZE        RSIZE        PSIZE        VGROW        RGROW      SWAPSZ       RUID           EUID            MEM      CMD         1/6
  30705            -            0            0         2.7M       10.2M        90.1M       132.0K         0.0K      241.5M        78.0M        71.3M           0B           0B          0B       flask          flask            8%      gunicorn
  30704            -            0            0         2.7M       10.2M        87.9M       132.0K         0.0K      239.3M        75.6M        69.0M           0B           0B          0B       flask          flask            8%      gunicorn
    170            -            2            6        92.0K        8.8M        49.2M       132.0K         0.0K      227.3M        44.1M        34.2M           0B           0B          0B       root           root             5%      systemd-journa
  30741            -            0            0         5.8M       16.5M         7.1M       132.0K         0.0K      215.5M        33.5M        14.7M           0B           0B          0B       postgres       postgres         3%      postgres
  30739            -            0            0         5.8M       16.5M         7.7M       132.0K         0.0K      216.1M        32.2M        14.1M           0B           0B          0B       postgres       postgres         3%      postgres
    212            -            0            0        80.0K        6.2M        18.0M       132.0K       282.5M      282.5M        26.7M        22.6M           0B           0B          0B       root           root             3%      multipathd
    496            -            0            0        18.7M        1.8M       166.2M       132.0K         0.0K      710.3M        22.8M        25.3M           0B           0B          0B       root           root             2%      snapd
  30699            -            0            0         2.7M        5.6M        21.0M       132.0K         0.0K       39.1M        22.0M        16.7M           0B           0B          0B       flask          flask            2%      gunicorn
  92773            -          416            0        63.6M        3.5M        43.0M       132.0K         0.0K      304.3M        20.5M        10.7M       226.3M         5.9M          0B       flask          flask            2%      node
  92779            -          454            0        63.6M        3.4M        41.9M       132.0K         0.0K      303.2M        19.6M         9.5M       233.3M         9.7M          0B       flask          flask            2%      node
    658            -            0            0         5.8M       16.3M         2.0M       132.0K         0.0K      210.1M        15.6M         4.1M           0B           0B          0B       postgres       postgres         2%      postgres
    720            -            0            0         5.8M       16.3M         2.2M       132.0K         0.0K      210.3M        14.0M         4.0M           0B           0B          0B       postgres       postgres         1%      postgres
    476            -            0            0         2.7M        8.4M        10.4M       132.0K         0.0K       32.4M        13.2M         9.5M           0B           0B          0B       root           root             1%      networkd-dispa
    638            -            0            0         2.7M       11.0M        17.1M       132.0K         0.0K      107.5M        11.0M         8.2M           0B           0B          0B       root           root             1%      unattended-upg
      1            -           43            0       896.0K        8.8M        19.4M         1.0M         0.0K       99.8M        10.1M         6.7M           0B        28.0K          0B       root           root             1%      systemd
  92751            -          543            0       172.0K        2.5M         4.7M       948.0K         9.7M        9.7M         9.6M         6.6M         1.2M         1.2M          0B       root           root             1%      atop
   1178            -            0            0         8.9M        8.0K       103.1M       132.0K         0.0K        1.2G         8.4M        12.8M           0B           0B          0B       root           root             1%      ssm-agent-work
    424            -            0            0       308.0K       12.0M         3.5M       132.0K         0.0K       24.8M         8.2M         4.9M           0B           0B          0B       systemd-       systemd-         1%      systemd-resolv
    721            -            0            0         5.8M       16.3M         2.0M
```

```
ATOP - ip-172-31-3-66                                                           2022/10/18  00:02:01                                                           -----------------                                                            1m0s elapsed
PRC | sys   59.57s | user   0.37s |               |              | #proc    145 |              | #trun      2 | #tslpi   115 |               | #tslpu    73 | #zombie    0 |              | clones     4 |               |              | #exit      0 |
CPU | sys      99% |              | user      0%  | irq       1% |              |              | idle      0% |              |  wait      0% |              | steal     0% | guest     0% |              |               | curf 2.40GHz |              |
CPL | avg1   23.95 |              | avg5    8.69  |              | avg15   3.26 |              |              |              |  csw   121213 |              | intr   73529 |              |              |               | numcpu     1 |              |
MEM | tot   966.2M | free   65.4M | cache 154.7M  | dirty   0.0M | buff    0.1M | slab   58.9M | slrec  24.8M |              |               | shmem 138.0M | shrss   0.0M | shswp   0.0M |              |               |              | numnode    1 |
SWP | tot     0.0M |              | free    0.0M  |              | swcac   0.0M |              |              |              |               |              |              |              | vmcom   1.4G |               | vmlim 483.1M |              |
PAG | scan 70955e3 | steal 1948e3 |               | stall      0 | compact    0 | numamig    0 |              | migrate    0 |               |              |              |              | swin       0 |  swout      0 |              | oomkill    0 |
PSI | cpusome  25% | memsome  99% |               | memfull  83% | iosome  100% |              | iofull    0% | cs  27/23/12 |               | ms  99/83/31 | mf  82/70/26 |              | is 100/84/31 |  if     0/0/0 |              |              |
DSK |         xvda | busy    100% |               | read   57692 | write     69 | discrd     0 |              | KiB/r     65 |  KiB/w      5 | KiB/d      0 |              | MBr/s   61.0 | MBw/s    0.0 |  avq    22.51 |              | avio 1.04 ms |
DSK |        xvda1 | busy    100% |               | read   57692 | write     69 | discrd     0 |              | KiB/r     65 |  KiB/w      5 | KiB/d      0 |              | MBr/s   61.0 | MBw/s    0.0 |  avq    22.51 |              | avio 1.04 ms |
NET | transport    | tcpi       0 |               | tcpo       0 | udpi       8 | udpo       8 |              | tcpao      0 |  tcppo      0 | tcprs      0 |              | tcpie      0 | tcpor      0 |  udpnp      0 |              | udpie      0 |
NET | network      |              | ipi        8  | ipo        8 |              | ipfrw      0 | deliv      8 |              |               |              |              |              |              |  icmpi      0 | icmpo      0 |              |
NET | lo      ---- |              | pcki       8  | pcko       8 |              | sp    0 Mbps | si    0 Kbps | so    0 Kbps |               |              | coll       0 | mlti       0 | erri       0 |  erro       0 | drpi       0 | drpo       0 |
NET | eth0    ---- |              | pcki       1  | pcko       1 |              | sp    0 Mbps | si    0 Kbps | so    0 Kbps |               |              | coll       0 | mlti       0 | erri       0 |  erro       0 | drpi       0 | drpo       0 |

    PID          TID       MINFLT       MAJFLT       VSTEXT      VSLIBS        VDATA       VSTACK       LOCKSZ       VSIZE        RSIZE        PSIZE        VGROW        RGROW      SWAPSZ       RUID           EUID            MEM      CMD         1/7
  30705            -          729         3985         2.7M       10.2M        90.1M       132.0K         0.0K      241.5M        74.4M        69.6M           0B       132.0K          0B       flask          flask            8%      gunicorn
  30704            -          697         4022         2.7M       10.2M        87.9M       132.0K         0.0K      239.3M        72.0M        67.2M           0B        -0.4M          0B       flask          flask            7%      gunicorn
  92777            -          396         2827         2.7M       10.1M        42.1M       132.0K         0.0K       69.6M        43.8M        41.5M           0B       700.0K          0B       flask          flask            5%      python
  92780            -          642         2963         2.7M       10.1M        42.1M       132.0K         0.0K       69.6M        43.6M        41.5M           0B       772.0K          0B       flask          flask            5%      python
  92776            -           23         2432         2.7M       10.1M        42.4M       132.0K         0.0K       69.6M        43.3M        40.9M         4.3M       772.0K          0B       flask          flask            4%      python
  92786            -          622         2998         2.7M        6.1M        42.0M       132.0K         0.0K       60.8M        43.0M        41.0M           0B        -0.4M          0B       flask          flask            4%      python
  92782            -          715         2977         2.7M        6.1M        42.0M       132.0K         0.0K       60.8M        42.7M        41.0M           0B        -0.1M          0B       flask          flask            4%      python
  92783            -          583         2985         2.7M        6.1M        42.0M       132.0K         0.0K       60.8M        42.6M        41.0M           0B        -0.3M          0B       flask          flask            4%      python
  92775            -          737         2983         2.7M        6.1M        42.0M       132.0K         0.0K       60.8M        42.6M        41.0M           0B       600.0K          0B       flask          flask            4%      python
  92767            -          675         2969         2.7M        6.1M        42.0M       132.0K         0.0K       60.8M        42.2M        40.6M           0B        -0.4M          0B       flask          flask            4%      python
  92778            -          238         2779         2.7M        6.1M        42.0M       132.0K         0.0K       60.8M        42.1M        40.8M           0B        -0.2M          0B       flask          flask            4%      python
  30741            -            0            0         5.8M       16.5M         7.1M       132.0K         0.0K      215.5M        27.5M        12.7M           0B           0B          0B       postgres       postgres         3%      postgres
    212            -            0            0        80.0K        6.2M        18.0M       132.0K       282.5M      282.5M        26.7M        22.6M           0B           0B          0B       root           root             3%      multipathd
  30739            -            0            0         5.8M       16.5M         7.7M       132.0K         0.0K      216.1M        26.6M        12.2M           0B           0B          0B       postgres       postgres         3%      postgres
  30699            -          563         2647         2.7M        5.6M        21.0M       132.0K         0.0K       39.1M        22.4M        16.5M           0B       512.0K          0B       flask          flask            2%      gunicorn
    496            -            2           70        18.7M        1.8M       166.2M       132.0K         0.0K      710.3M        16.5M        16.7M           0B           0B          0B       root           root             2%      snapd
    658            -           33          441         5.8M       16.3M         2.0M       132.0K         0.0K      210.1M        13.0M         3.8M           0B       300.0K          0B       postgres       postgres         1%      postgres
    720            -           47         1995         5.8M       16.3M         2.2M       132.0K         0.0K      210.3M        12.9M         3.7M           0B        -0.6M          0B       postgres       postgres         1%      postgres
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add `/proc/meminfo` under memory pressure. Likely is memory consumption for things other than anonymous space, that you are not accounting for.  Often when you see kswapd and other memory reclaim working that hard, you don't have enough memory to have a comfortable margin.

Comment: Notice that sometimes kswapd0 is not a system daemon, by merely a *Linux.Xor.DDoS* worm/trojan, so I'd check if it's a system process indeed. *Linux.Xor.DDoS* resides in /tmp and in  /var/lib/.rpm, so...